# Laravel 5.6: Eloquent + DB::Builder query array indexes

Tags: php, laravel-5, eloquent

I have two queries that return a collection. But with different ids I get different array indexes.

```
$worker = Worker::find($worker_id);
$man = $worker->managers->where('id', $manager_id)->first();
$tasks = $man->tasks->where('worker_id', $worker_id);
dd($tasks->toArray());
```

When I run this query with `$worker_id` of 1, I get an array with numeric index starting from 0:

```
[
 {
   "id": 1,
   "task_name": "Cleaning"
 },
 ....
]
```

But with `$worker_id` of 2, I get an array with named (string) indexes starting from "9":

```
[
 "9": {
   "id": 18,
   "task_name": "Staff reorientation"
 },
 "10": {
   "id": 19,
   "task_name": "Schedule"
 }
 ....
]
```

What may be the cause?

Comment: please add output here.

Comment: Added the output example.

Comment: türk olduğunu düşünerek türkçe yazıyorum, sorunun kaynağını bilmiyorum ancak `array_values()` metodunu kullanarak düzeltebilirsin. ayrıca tek bir sorgu ile yukarıdaki verileri çekebilirsin, ayrı ayrı her biri için istek atma gereksiz, ki muhtemelen bunu foreache sokuyorsan her ilişki için veritabanına istek atacak, sunucuyu çok yorabilir.

Comment: Tek sorguya dönüştürülmüş örnek yazabilir misin? Teşekkürler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Filtering a collection doesn't change the original keys. You can reset them with [`values()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/collections#method-values):

```
$tasks = $man->tasks->where('worker_id', $worker_id)->values();
```